# .Net WebBrowser Control using IE10

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

Is there any way (yet) to use the WebBrowser Control in the Internet Explorer 10 preview?

Preferable on Windows 7 but for starters Windows 8 would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use an unstable preview version of a rendering engine in your web browser control?

Comment: Why would you want to use an unstable dinosaur version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest IE10 preview is available only for Windows 8, however it has been said that the release version would run on Windows 7 also.
I was able to use the WebBrowser Control in the IE 10 preview mode by adding the below line to the html file. " meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" "